# Reinstalling uninstalled window updates

Tags: updates, windows-xp

I've uninstalled some updates recently, I'd like to reinstall them. Any chance to get notified again through automatic window updates utility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Internet Explorer, go to the toolbar Tools>Windows Update.

.

[image]

.

If you want to use other means to check, you can install MBSA and run it on your PC.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b1e76bbe-71df-41e8-8b52-c871d012ba78

.

Comment: I visited their site but its not checking for updates that I have already uninstalled.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but it will check for any missing updates. I did an edit on my post, please check it.